# How to access the data variable values of a bound method mapping.values of xarray.Dataset in Python

Tags: python, python-xarray

how can I access the data variable values of a bound method mapping.values of xarray.Dataset, what is the correct syntax:

I would need to retrieve the pm2p5_conc Data variable:

```py
pmScatter["pm25"].values

array([<bound method Mapping.values of <xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     ()
Coordinates:
    level       float32 0.0
    time        timedelta64[ns] 00:00:00
    longitude   float64 2.352
    latitude    float64 48.86
Data variables:
    pm2p5_conc  float64 26.23
Attributes:
    title:        PM25 Air Pollutant FORECAST at 8 levels
    institution:  Data produced by Meteo France
    source:       Data from ENSEMBLE model
    history:      Model ENSEMBLE FORECAST
    FORECAST:     Europe, 20210325-20210327+[0H_0H]
    summary:      ENSEMBLE model hourly FORECAST of PM25 concentration at 8 l...
    project:      MACC-RAQ (http://macc-raq.gmes-atmosphere.eu)>,
       <bound method Mapping.values of <xarray.Dataset>
```

[Data variable pm2p5_conc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gscCJ.png)

Following dl.meteos's advice I get a Key Error:

```py
    def normalize(x):
        return 0.5 + (x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min())

risk = normalize(pmScatter["pm25"]["pm2p5_conc"].values)* pop.pop_2010[::resolution].values * normalize(covidExtra.hosp[::resolution].values) gives me the following error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-47c4a255de66> in <module>
----> 1 risk = normalize(pmScatter["pm25"]["pm2p5_conc"].values)* pop.pop_2010[::resolution].values * normalize(covidExtra.hosp[::resolution].values)
      2 risk = np.vstack((x,y,risk)).T
      3 risk = pd.DataFrame(risk,columns=['lon','lat','risk'])
      4 

~/.pyenv/versions/lewagon/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    851 
    852         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 853             return self._get_value(key)
    854 
    855         if is_hashable(key):

~/.pyenv/versions/lewagon/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
    959 
    960         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
--> 961         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
    962         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
    963 

~/.pyenv/versions/lewagon/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    352                 except ValueError as err:
    353                     raise KeyError(key) from err
--> 354             raise KeyError(key)
    355         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
    356 

KeyError: 'pm2p5_conc'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are access the `xarray.Dataset` using values method which yields to a type casting reverting a numpy array.

The solution is quite easy:

```
pmScatter["pm25"]["pm2p5_conc"].values
```

Calling `.values` on a `xarray.DataArray`. Please take a look into the xarray Documentation to learn the difference between `DataArray` and `Dataset`.

Comment: Hi dl.meteo, I have already tried that but I get a key error: please see above in the description

Comment: Take a look into: `list(pmScatter["pm25"].keys())`

Comment: type(pmScatter["pm25"]) is pandas.core.series.Series

Comment: So the keys are integer indices

Comment: Can you just print out : print(pmScatter["pm25"])

Comment: type(pmScatter["pm25"][0]) is method

Comment: print(pmScatter["pm25"]) : 4       <bound method Mapping.values of <xarray.Datase...
                              ...                        
3627    <bound method Mapping.values of <xarray.Datase...

Comment: I solved this issue by converting the dataset to an array with the to_array() function before applying an interpolation method on it